# How do I debug this heroku rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a ruby on rails application that I am hosting on heroku. The root page does not work and gives a 404 error. Other pages on the app work. At first I could not replicate the error locally but later ran the local WEBrick in production mode and replicated the error as a migration error. I have now run migrations on heroku via `heroku run rake db:migrate` with no error but the problem still persists. The local logs exposed the migration error but the heroku logs have not been helpful.

**EDIT:**

Found a solution with the help of another stackoverflow answer. After figuring out it was the root page only that was throwing 404 I edited my routes.rb. Moved the resources code above the routes and changed `root to: 'static_pages#home'` to `get "/" => 'static_pages#home', :as => 'root'` and it works!

Comment: can you put the heroku's error description by doing what @antpaw said?

Comment: Can I just copy and paste the log from the terminal?

Comment: Use `heroku run rails console` and make sure your migrations worked.

Comment: After `heroku run rails console` what command do I use next? I get an undefined method 'migrate' for main:object with `heroku run rake db:migrate`

Comment: rollback or drop your db using `heroku run rake db:drop` and re-migrate

Comment: Your solution sounds like it will solve the problem but I cannot drop the database. It gives a "User does not have connect privilege" error

Answer (score 0):

try `heroku logs` in terminal. that should give you the error

Comment: you should paste some output from the logs when you encounter that error. It's likely there.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this problem. Solution is to catch errors by any Error Catching service.

I'm using  [Airbrake](https://www.airbrake.io) (free for light projects or devlopment) for catching actual errors. Heroku logs are not usable, only for fast look on general problems.